# Fitting noise with Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm

Tags: analysis, nonlinear-optimization

I've got a sample of noise from a microphone, and I'm trying to fit a curve to the data using the [Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm).  However, I can't seem to find a good starting function.

I've tried a couple different ones, like the example on the wiki page: $F(x) = A\cos(Bx) + B\sin(Ax)$.  The biggest problem with this is that I get harmonic areas where the two components cancel themselves out.  I might be able to reduce this by adding more sin and cos terms, but I figured I'd come ask here first, as I'm sure you guys would know much better than me.

I'm actually not even sure if what I'm doing is feasible.  I'm worried that microphone noise might be too random to fit, even with a great starting function.  What do you guys think?

Edit: Looking at it a little more, it does seem to be too random.  I was hoping that a few frequencies might stand out enough to fit the curve, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  I suppose you could give it a starting function with several dozen sine waves added together, but then the algorithm would become far too slow to be practical.  :/

Comment: Can you first apply a filter to remove any high frequency data and then try curve fitting after?

Comment: I considered that.  I'll give it a try tomorrow, but I'm still worried that there are just too many waves stacked on top of each other to accurately model.

Comment: I don't really know about your data and I'm certainly not an expert but after you filter the high frequency you could use polynomial interpolation via sampling your signal at some frequency and fitting via something like this http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/publication/PDF/2004_106.pdf